# How to change the first letter of each word from lowercase to uppercase without using arrays in C?

Tags: c

My code below converts whole letters of the text to uppercase letters. However, I need to capitalize each word from the file **without using arrays, function and etc. Using ASCII.**

poem.txt:

```
The house cat sits

And smiles and sings

He knows a lot

Of secret things
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{

FILE *input;
FILE *output;

input  = fopen ("poem.txt", "r");
output = fopen ("poem_modified.txt", "w");

if (input == NULL || output == NULL)
{
    printf("Problem! \n");
    return 1;
}
int ch;

while((ch=getc(input)) != EOF)
{
  if( ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z' )
  {
        ch = ch - 32;
  }
  fprintf(output, "%c", ch);
}

fclose(input);
fclose(output); 

}
```

Comment: Begin by figuring out how to detect a new word. Once you have that down then use [`toupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper) for capitalization.

Comment: What about a boolean that you set to true whenever you see the word ends, which you then use as an extra condition for your capitalisation if-statement?

Comment: how about use fscanf to read a hole word not just read a char. You need to check fscanf function

Comment: @JumHorn "**[W]ithout using arrays**" Can't read strings without an array to hold the string.

Comment: sorry about that. in fact if you use char or int these variables are stored on stack. if you use char arr[30] this is also stored on stack. I believe there is no much difference

Comment: Second question in this style from the same person in only a few hours... Are we being treated to your homework assignments, or, perhaps you have a new book of "Programming Challenges in C for a Rainy Afternoon"... Where are these questions coming from?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `toupper()` is a function, and functions are not allowed. Fun little game from some fun little book, no doubt...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Doh!!! My bad... `fopen()`, `getc()`, `fprintf()` and `fclose()` are ALL functions... Guess the program is to use telepathy to read the contents of the file... `:-)` G'night...

Comment: https://i2.paste.pics/4e0837750f728596991ff22fc749d027.png hehehe

Comment: When posting questions about homework or similar assignments, then please always include the actual assignment or exercise, copy-pasted in full and complete, with all limitations and all requirements. That will help us understand what you're supposed to do as well as what can be done to solve it within the scope of the requirements and limitations.

Comment: Thank you everybody, @Someprogrammerdude, I will make sure of it next time)

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ASCII_LOWER(c) ((c) >= 'a' && (c) <= 'z')
#define WHITESPACE(c) ((c) == ' ' || (c) == '\t' || (c) == '\n')

int main (void)
{
    const char *ifname = "poem.txt";
    const char *ofname = "poem_modified.txt";
    FILE *ifp, *ofp;
    int prevch = ' ', ch;

    if ((ifp = fopen(ifname, "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open the file '%s'\n", ifname);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } else if ((ofp = fopen(ofname, "w")) == NULL) {
        fclose(ifp);
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open the file '%s'\n", ofname);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while ((ch = fgetc(ifp)) != EOF) {
        if (ASCII_LOWER(ch) && WHITESPACE(prevch))
            ch += 'A' - 'a';
        fputc(ch, ofp);
        prevch = ch;
    }

    fclose(ifp);
    fclose(ofp);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't be bothered with the whole `fgetc()` schmozzle... This simulates one character at a time from a compile time **array** of characters (which is exactly the same as the hidden array `fgetc()` uses...

```
int main() {

    char str[] =
        "The house cat sits\n\n"
        "And smiles and sings\n\n"
        "He knows a lot\n\n"
        "Of secret things\n" ;
    
    bool inw = false;
    for( int i = 0; str[i]; i++ ) {
        char c = str[i]; // here is 'fgetc()'

        if( ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') || ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') ) {
            if( inw == false && c >= 'a' )
                c -= 'a' - 'A';
            inw = true;
        } else inw = false;
        putchar( c );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  FILE *input;
  FILE *output;

  input = fopen("poem.txt", "r");
  output = fopen("poem_modified.txt", "w");

  if (input == NULL || output == NULL)
  {
     printf("Problem! \n");
     return 1;
  }
  int ch, track = 0;

  while ((ch = getc(input)) != EOF)
  {
     if (track == 0)
     {
        ch &= ~(1 << 5);
        track = -1;
     }
     if (ch == ' ')
        track = 0;
     fprintf(output, "%c", ch);
  }

  fclose(input);
  fclose(output);

}
```

> There's a simple way to convert lowercase to uppercase. If you carefully notice the ASCII value of each lowercase and uppercase letter the you will get to know that the fifth bit is set in lowercase.

**A -> 1000001**
**a -> 1100001**

> And, so we need to set only the fifth bit. (1<<5) gives a number whose fifth bit is unset and and negation of ~(1<<5) gives a number whose bit is set only. And if we perform the bitwise and (&) operation with the letter then we'll get the uppercase letter.
> I've initalized a varibale name track=0, and in the begining it converts the first letter to upercase and change it's to -1. And whenever we get a space(' ') change track to 0.